# Can't find project or library - Reference option cannot be selected & modules are frozen

Tags: vba

I have this problem occur regularly with different workbooks. The file opens with:

> Can't find project or library

I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to open the VBA editor. I try clicking on References in the Tools menu but it doesn't do anything. I try editing the modules but I can't see any code and the windows are frozen.  See attached file.

[image]

Comment: Do any of these workbooks run macros located in another file?

Comment: I would first try reinstalling MS Office.

Answer (score 1):

This is a guess, but sounds like there is a macro is running on 'open' of your spreadsheet, but the library it needs is missing (due to early binding, and a missing reference, often due to a different version of office).

1. Turn your macro settings to 'ask before running' - in office 265,
   this is file-->options-->trust center-->trust center
   settings-->macro settings-->disable all macros with notification.
2. reopen the file, but Don't enable the macro
3. press alt+f11 to enter the macro editor, then look at tools--> references for the
   missing reference and try and fix.
4. Save and relaunch your spreadsheet, and enable macros

Comment: worked for me, just save my life. Thank you, RowanC.
Just to add 1 thing to Step 3: to know what reference is missing, you can open other new excel file (parallel with the corrupted file). Now, missing reference in corrupted file should appear as same as the new file, then just tick them.